# как конвертировать string в char.IsLower

Tags: c#

есть программа

```
using System;

public class MainClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        char a = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
        if (char.IsLower(a))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(char.ToUpper(a));
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(char.ToLower(a));
        }
    }
}
```

Она принимает символ нижнего или верхнего регистра, и выводит его или в верхнем или в нижнем регистре. Но это только с символами, как сделать так чтобы программа могла принимать тип string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте ToList(), этот метод превращает `string` в `List<char>`

Нужный вам код:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
for(int i = 0; i < chars.Count; i += 1)
   if(char.IsLower(input[i]))
      input[i] = char.ToUpper(input[i]);
   else input[i] = char.ToLower(input[i]);
// Теперь input - выходная строка
```

Нужный вам код с Linq:

```
string output = string.Concat(Console.ReadLine().Select(x => char.IsLower(x) ? char.ToUpper(x) : char.ToLower(x)));
```

Comment: Только не `:x`, а `:ToLower(x)`, там инверсия по постановке. И в не-linq варианте тоже `else` нужно

Comment: @Zufir, спасибо, исправил

Comment: Можешь пожалуйста объяснить, что делает list<char> и 4-5 строчка

Comment: @rBTI, List<char> это массив символов, но только не имеет размерности, то есть ты можешь в него добавлять хоть сколько ещё новых элементов, когда обычный массив так не может, т.к при инициализации ты указывает размер массива
Мне лично было сложно понять синтаксис List, когда я ещё учил C# в школе

Comment: В 4 и 5 строке же берётся по индексу символ и проверяется на IsLower, и так же по индексу изменяется, конечно, можно использовать и второй список чтобы добавлять в него новые символы, не изменяя старый список

Comment: @Yotic Спасибо что объяснил

Comment: Что в первом, что во 2-м варианте, `.ToList()` бесполезен от слова совсем, ведь `string` - это и так коллекция, вы можете сразу делать `char first = "123"[0];`, или `foreach (var chr in "123"){}`, ну и т.д. Далее, `new string(chars);` - лучше переделать в `string.Concat(chars)`, как минимум по причине, что .NET версия не позволит вам использовать `new string()` из коллекций, а как максимум - скорость. Ну и последнее `char.IsLower(chars[x])` - запускайте перед публикацией код, чтоб не было таких опечаток.

Comment: К предыдущему комменту: есть же `.ToCharArray()` на худой конец. Зачем эти списки там, где не надо делать изменение состава коллекции? Мелденнее работают, чем массивы и больше жрут памяти. И из массива `new string` можно делать.

Comment: `input[i] = char.ToUpper(input[i]);` недопустимая операция. Строку можно читать как массив символов, но нельзя писать.

Answer (score 2):

делаем +- то же самое что и в коде из вопроса

```
public class MainClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var line = Console.ReadLine();
        
        if (line.ToLower() == line)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line.ToUpper());
        } else { 
            Console.WriteLine(line.ToLower());
        }
    }
}
```

стоит заметить что автор вопроса не написал что должно случится в случае если в строке символы различных регистров поэтому я стандартным поведением сделал переведении строки в нижний регистр

---

если же нужно было в строке сделать это с каждым отдельным символом - т.е. сделать каждый символ противоположным регистром, то такое необходимо писать в вопросе прямым текстом!!!!

```
using System.Linq;

public class MainClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var line = Console.ReadLine().ToCharArray();
        
        var convertedLine = line.Select( a => Char.IsLower(a) ? Char.ToUpper(a) : Char.ToLower(a) );
        
        var rez = string.Concat(convertedLine);
        
        Console.WriteLine(rez);
    }
}
```